# How to align button and input (on form), and pull them right on a bootstrap panel-heading

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I have a bootstrap panel with a title on the left, and button on the right.
I can't align them correctly because one of them is an input (a form rendered by twig template, it's a symfony project).

Here is a jsfiddle exemple :
https://jsfiddle.net/yornletard/9vbr7awb/

```
<div class="panel panel-info">
  <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
    <h3 class="panel-title pull-left" style="padding-top: 7.5px;">Echantillon : origine</h3>
    <div class="btn-group pull-right">
      <a href="/fr/sample/12/edit">
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Modifier</button>
      </a>
      <form name="form" method="post" action="/fr/sample/12">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
        <input type="submit" value=" Supprimer l'échantillon" class="fa btn btn-info btn-sm">
        <input type="hidden" id="form__token" name="form[_token]" value="uBwVtOMyGwX0omj_5gLkEAGvzHkNvH5L1NXUsVKYFr4">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
  Echantillon : origine
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how're you trying to align them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<form>` is rendered with `display: block;` by default so you have to overwrite this behaviour by using `display: inline-block;`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="panel panel-info">
  <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
    <h3 class="panel-title pull-left" style="padding-top: 7.5px;">Echantillon : origine</h3>
    <div class="btn-group pull-right">
      <a href="/fr/sample/12/edit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Modifier</a>
      <form name="form" style="display:inline-block" method="post" action="/fr/sample/12">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
        Supprimer l'échantillon
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks !! I just have to see how I customize form rendering in symfony !